# Change size of individual point symbols in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have some point data (towns) with population levels. I'd like to show the smaller populations with small dot and increase the size of the dot symbol as the population increases.

I can do this in Mapinfo but I want to do it in QGIS.

Comment: Possible closer to a duplicate of the above or some other question that deals with data defined rendering https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=data+defined+properties